# React props only update on render when re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

When I try re-rendering a react component with different props compared to the initial render, I can only see the updated prop values when render is called. All previous lifecycle methods return the old prop value.

For example, the following code...

```
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps");
    console.log(this.props.calls);
}

shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log("shouldComponentUpdate");
    console.log(this.props.calls);
    return true;
}

componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log("componentWillUpdate");
    console.log(this.props.calls);
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate");
    console.log(this.props.calls);
}

render() {
    console.log("render");
    console.log(this.props.calls);
}
```

when rerendered with new props will return...

```
componentWillReceiveProps
oldProp
shouldComponentUpdate
oldProp
componentWillUpdate
oldProp
render
newProp
componentDidUpdate
newProp
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and advise how I can get the updated prop before rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Life Cycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods) methods that are part of the update process (`componentWillReceiveProps`, `shouldComponentUpdate`, `componentWillUpdate`) happen before the actual props are updated. To get the new props, for example to check if a component should update in `shouldComponentUpdate`, react passes the new props as params to the method.

So to get the new props, you need to do this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps");
    console.log(nextProps.calls);
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log("shouldComponentUpdate");
    console.log(nextProps.calls);
    return true;
}

componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log("componentWillUpdate");
    console.log(nextProps.calls);
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("componentDidUpdate");
    console.log(this.props.calls);
}

render() {
    console.log("render");
    console.log(this.props.calls);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

New props will be in the params of mentioned functions.

E.g. `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)`

- `this.props` are the old props
- `newProps` are the new props.

> Updating: componentWillReceiveProps

```
void componentWillReceiveProps(
  object nextProps
)
```

> Invoked when a component is receiving new props. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to react to a prop transition before render() is called by updating the state using this.setState(). The old props can be accessed via this.props. Calling this.setState() within this function will not trigger an additional render.

The same works for other methods as well.

Please, check the [docs for details](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html)